# How can I write nested formGroups in a table without violating the rules of HTML?

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I'm creating a table where is a row is one formGroup, and some of the cells are in another form. This works (simplified for clarity):

```
<tr formArrayName="channels" role="row" *ngFor="let channel of form.get('channels').controls; let i=index">
    <td [formGroupName]="i">
        <input formControlName="channelName" type="text" /> 
    </td>
    <div [formGroupName]="i">
        <td formArrayName="tasks" *ngFor="let task of channel.get('tasks').controls; let j=index">
            <div [formGroupName]="j">
                <input formControlName="taskName" type="text" />
            </div>
        </td>
    </div>
</tr>
```

But as you can see there is a `div` directly surrounding the second `td`, which violates the structure of HTML. If I try adding the `formGroupName` attribute directly to the `td` I get a compilation error:

`ERROR Error: Cannot find control with path: 'channels -> 0 -> 0'`

`channels` is a formArray with several `formControls`, and each channel includes a nested `tasks` formArray with several `formControls` in each task which seems like the right organisation for calculations I will need to do in typescript. Is there anyway to write the HTML without the `div` and without flattening the nested structure of the `formControls`?

Comment: use ng-container https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#ng-container-to-the-rescue

Comment: Hmmm, when I switched out the `div` for `ng-template` the cells didn't render at all (no error).

Comment: ng-container, not ng-template. But PUT the [formGroupName]="i" in the div with *ngFor and formArrayName in a div outer (you're iterating over a FormArray)

Comment: Do you mean `td`? I can't use divs.

Comment: Actually ng-container on the formgroup works fine.

Comment: strange that ng-template didn't work for you and then it did. ng-container as recommended by @Eliseo did the job for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr formArrayName="channels" role="row" *ngFor="let channel of form.get('channels').controls; let i=index">
    <td [formGroupName]="i">
        <input formControlName="channelName" type="text" /> 
    </td>
    <div [formGroupName]="i">
       <div formArrayName="tasks">
        <td  *ngFor="let task of channel.get('tasks').controls; let j=index">
            <div [formGroupName]="j">
                <input formControlName="taskName" type="text" />
            </div>
        </td>
       </div>
    </div>
</tr>
```

Comment: Can you add an explanation about what is different about this code? Why does this fix the problem?